# Making monthly reporting program about Cisco product

Tags: python, networking, cisco

I'm running a network infra consisted with Cisco product.

I'm trying to make a ordinary network monthly reporting program with Python.

I have never made any program before, So I think you guys have better way to do it.

Check my plan and teach me that is a good idea or not.

my plan as below.

1. Connect to Network Machine and collect log

   - telnet x.x.x.x
   - collect "show command"
   - save that log as text file
     ※ this action may run in telnet client program(like a SecureCRT)
2. open the text file and make a report

   - ex) combine "Show interface status" / "Show ip interface brief" / "Show ip arp" / "Show mac address-table" to make "Interface/IP/Mac/Port/Status" Report

This is my approximate plan.

Do you think it is efficient way? I need your teaching.

and I wonder how do you guys do similar job in datacenter.

Answer (score 0):

We use Monitoring Tools for such tasks.
There are plenty of Open Source applications such as NeDi, Cacti and so on.

Why do you want to use "show" commands instead of using SNMP to get the device information?

Also I'd recommend to use SSH instead of telnet (for security reasons).

Cheers